# Energy of particle in equilibrium

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, mass-energy

Suppose I have a mass let say a mass of M kg
Imagine, it is in equilibrium
No force is acting on it
Due to no force its energy must be zero .
But why it is said that mass at rest also has energy associated with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is said"? Are you referring to the $E=mc^2$ of relativity? Where does the idea that things that have no forces acting on them must have zero energy come from?

Comment: What about the possibility of gravitational potential energy? Kinetic energy with respect to another inertial reference frame? Internal energy? Mass energy (1/2 $mc^2$)?

Comment: Yes mr. Bob , I want to know what mass energy is  and what does it mean that when someone say that energy is associated with mass

Comment: Acurious mind, if a there is no force on a object then its energy is also zero

Comment: Obviously meant $mc^2$

Comment: See Einsteins Nov 21 1905 paper for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Yes a mass at rest will have a characteristic energy called rest energy. It is a sum of all energies of its molecules their Kinetic energies, potential energies, other energies too. Einstein claimed mass as sum of its energies.

You could find more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass

Answer (score 0):

This question is based on a couple of mistaken premises. First, equilibrium does not imply that there is no force, it only implies that there is no net force. Consider for example a spring which can be in equilibrium by being compressed by two opposing forces. Second, it is simply not true that the energy must be zero if there is no force acting on it. As you already noted there is the rest energy, $E=mc^2$. But there is also all sorts of other energy that something with no force may possess. KE, chemical potential energy, other potential energy, thermal energy, etc.

Once the incorrect premises are dismissed there is no more question remaining